# a solderless breadboard alternative allowing point to point wiring by pushing the wire between special bifurcated pins?

Tags: breadboard

Does anyone remember what was the name of the manufacturer who made a solderless breadboard alternative allowing point to point wiring by pushing the wire between special bifurcated pins on the back of the board. All that was needed was a little plastic "pusher" tool. I picked one up at the Ideas In Science and Electronics" show in Albuquerque in the '8os, but passed it on to someone else.

I used it and it was a LOT faster than wire wrap, and was claimed to offer as good or better contacts.

Thanks for answering. The bifurcated end of the pins were like opposing miniature knife blades that cut through the insulation and a bit into the wire to make a gas-tight connection. You could push more than one wire - I think as many as 3 - onto the same pin. The only drawback was that since you were working on the bottom of the board, there was the problem of keeping track of the pin order. This was helped by getting little number-pattern labels that were made just for this purpose and pushing them over the pin layout of the IC, only from the bottom. Then no problem.

I've been searching, and Speedwire is the system that seems closest, but it's no longer available, and I think what I'm searching for was an American-made product. I'd get a Speedwire board immediately, 'tho.

Comment: What does a bifurcated pin look like?

Comment: It's got a single pin at one end, and two blades at the other.

Comment: Sounds like the same technology as telecom punchdown blocks.

Comment: Yup, punchdown blocks, w/ the tool being a spudger.  I've never heard of a breadboard alternative for prototyping, though.

Answer (score 1):

You mean [THESE](http://www.vectorelect.com/Catpdf/New%20Page%2073.pdf)? 
[image]

One of my first major projects used them.  There were two varieties from vector that I used -- One like this, the three pronged style, which was amenable for wire wrap, and one that was sort of flatter, like this, better for solder

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of the 3M Breadboard System?

[image]